# Content for directive loaded dynamically not showing when using templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, directive

We have the following directive:

```
angular.module("MyApp")
    .directive('documentViewer', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            },
            templateUrl: "templates/documentViewer.tpl.html"
        }
    });
```

On the page, we have a grid and for each row in the grid there is a link which the user can click. When the user clicks this link, we are trying to show a pop up from within the page's controller:

```
self.viewDocument = function (docId) {
    var title = "Document Viewer";
    var body = $compile('<document-viewer></document-viewer>')($scope);
    showBootstrapModalDialog(title, body, true, true, false);
};
```

In the Network tab on the Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the template specified is being fetched, however, the content does not show on the pop-up. You can see it here: [Screenshot of pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrDIE.png)

Here is the contents of the template:

```
<div>
    document viewer template
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need to use $compile?

something like this sure do the trick

```
self.viewDocument = function (docId) {
 $scope.currentDoc = docId;
};

<div>
  ...
  <document-viewer ng-if='currentDoc'></document-viewer>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The contents of the document-viewer will be different whenever one of the links are clicked, with this approach it is only calling the link() function once and content is not changing, any ideas?

Comment: pass everything you need into the directive as attributes. those will be available an the link function, and you can do what ever you want with them. 



<document-viewer attr1='foo' attr2='bar' ng-if='currentDoc'></document-viewer>

Comment: I'm passing the documentId into the directive, however, the link function only gets called 1 time when the first link is clicked. After another link is clicked, it's not called again and the directive's content remains the same with contents from the first link that was clicked.

Comment: This is where binding comes in. see for example https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/dVaryX?editors=1010#0

Comment: Thanks, was able to get it working by following your example. Needed to wrap the call to pull the HTML before showing the pop-up in timeout to give angular a chance to update the view.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.
I'll appreciate if you'll mark the answer as useful, I'm trying to raise my score :)